# Regression for no representative sample

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, inference

Can I use regression analysis for data which are not representative to the whole population? I want to describe relations between Y and Xs but I have no ambition whatsoever to extrapolate behind this certain data sample (I'd most likely don't use any inferential statistics such as statistical significance or C.I.).

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Sure -- why not?

Comment: I thought so, but I had the feeling that I should rather ask. Anyway, in this case reporting S.E. would be meaningless. Is there any other way to report standard deviation (other than in separated description statistics table) or this concept does not make sense?

Comment: SE doesn't describe the population, but the root mean square residual is a useful, meaningful statistic.  There are a great many other ways to describe a batch of 2D data besides formal regression analyses, too: focus on those properties you are interested in rather than those properties the software happens to offer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'll look into that.